# Serenity Cucumber 7 parallel execution not working

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-serenity, parallel-execution

looking for help to execute cucumber 7 in parallel. My project is serenity with cucumber and java. In this link https://johnfergusonsmart.com/parallel-test-execution-with-cucumber-and-serenity-bdd/ it is showing that it is possible to run but tried different combination and looks like I missed something.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.d</groupId>
<artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <serenity.version>3.2.0</serenity.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <tags></tags>
    <parallel.tests>4</parallel.tests>
    <webdriver.base.url></webdriver.base.url>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Runner*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.base.url>${webdriver.base.url}</webdriver.base.url>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
      <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <tags>${tags}</tags>
                <reports>single-page-html</reports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-single-page-report</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**To execute**:
I add same tag to multiple feature files and run through command line: mvn clean verify -Dtags="@regression"

**Expected**: Open multiple browsers at the same time to execute test faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution for parallel execution with cucumber 7 and serenity junit 4. Below pom.xml is tested and working to execute parallel. According to this pom.xml to execute two ways:

1. locally -  add to your runner in tags tag you want to run and then execute this command mvn clean verify
2. mvn clean verify -Dtags="@yourtagHere"

Working pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.d</groupId>
<artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <serenity.version>3.2.0</serenity.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <tags></tags>
    <parallel.tests>5</parallel.tests>
    <webdriver.base.url></webdriver.base.url>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
        <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.base.url>${webdriver.base.url}</webdriver.base.url>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>${parallel.tests}</threadCount>
                <!-- <forkCount>${parallel.tests}</forkCount>-->
                <!--<useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>-->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <tags>${tags}</tags>
                <reports>single-page-html</reports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-single-page-report</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Yuri I had similar issue and it required to use the 3.0.0-M3 failsafe plugin version. After that the tests started to run in parallel.

Did you run the tests remotely in parallel? Eg. Jenkins? I had issue to run them in parallel on Jenkins. The tests are randomly failing... I use xvfb plugin...

Comment: Hi @Vayas Zsolt Marton, my pom above is working with 3.0.0-M5 plugin. I run parallel on Azure DevOps and it is working. My virtual machine supports only two threads, so I change my threads to two. When I have more threads then I have the same random failure and some error about the driver.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was focus related. The tests lose focus in the browser window in case multiple tests are running on the same machine.

I moved the tests to run in headless mode and this it fixed the issue. I can now run 6 threads in parallel on the same machine without any random failure issue.